# Newline and whitespace error with santize gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sanitize

My Sanitize clean function changes code:

```
<h1>Test</h1>\r\n\r\n<ol>\r\n  <li>Foo</li>\r\n  <li>Bar</li>\r\n</ol>\r\n\r\n<p>Test end.</p>
```

to

```
<h1>Test</h1>\r\n\r\n<ol>\n<li>Foo</li>\r\n  <li>Bar</li>\r\n</ol><p>Test end.</p>"
```

The resulting sanitized code is almost totally identical; other than the return characters, the differences are very minor:

- The two spaces after the newline before the first list item (in ordered list)
  List item
- and the newlines after the closing ordered list tag.

Any thoughts on why this would be?